# Align heights with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Im using http://demo.agektmr.com/flexbox/ as reference, with following config:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="C">C</div>
  <div class="D">D</div>
  <div class="E">E</div>
</div>

.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap ;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Then I set different height for each box. They got vertically aligned in middle, but keeping their set heights.

How can I use flexbox so that boxes have flexible heights and all them fit to the biggest one?

A practical example is a basic website with 2 sidebars and a content column, and they have dynamic content and should all have same height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), changing `align-items: center;` to `align-items: stretch;` will do the trick.

Comment: Cool! thanks a lot! If .box doesn't have height it also grows as needed bu the biggest item.

Comment: It's worth noting that the default value for align-items is stretch.